# C# WPF: How to keep keyboard focus in main window?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, keyboard, focus

I am working on a simple image viewer.
It contains a viewbox which shows the current image.
Below I added a thumbnail strip created by a wrappanel inside a listview which contains the thumbnails in viewboxes again.

I am able to switch the current image by key events (code excample "space", in real space and arrow keys). By clicking in one of the thumbs it is also possible to update the current image.

Unfortunately, whenever I select a thumb in the Listview, the Mainwindow looses keyboard focus and I am not able to use the keys anymore to switch the images.

I tried all solutions found in the net, but nothing really works, now I am completely lost.

Any ideas.

```
     ...

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.command1}" CanExecute="command1CanExecute" Executed="handlecommand1"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.command1}"  Key="Space" />
</Window.InputBindings>

...

<DockPanel>
   <ListView x:Name="ThumbSlider"  ... Some Settings ... Focusable="False" MouseUp="ListboxMouseUp">
 <ListView.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.Resources>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Viewbox  ... Some Settings ... ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="120" Width="120" Focusable="False">
                   <Image Source="{Binding Path=ThumbImage}"></Image>
               </Viewbox>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   </ListView>      
   <Viewbox x:Name="CurrentImageBox" DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
       <Image Source="{Binding Path=CurrentImage}"/>
   </Viewbox>

   ...

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: You are doing everything with xaml?

Comment: I am not bound to xaml. I am also happy with a c# solution.
 
I tried for example.

private void ListboxMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { Keyboard.Focus(this); this.Focus(); }

Comment: It is not the ListView that takes the focus, the ListViewItems take focus when you click on them. All you need to do is to make the ListViewItems "unfocusable" (is that a word?). See here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/a8ecbb4a-b9eb-4aa1-b84f-51ba4521567a/listview-prevent-focus

Comment: I tried this examle before, with no result. I am not sure whether I am using it correctly with the template, I added the  focusable statment as shown in the updtated code above

Comment: Why don't you focus `CurrentImageBox` in `ListboxMouseUp` event handler after changing the image?

Comment: I just tried, but makes no difference.